# To pick the correct date format from UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, date

I have created an app to fetch the date of birth of a person. I have used UITextBox to take the user's date of birth from UIDatePicker(shows when user click on UITextBox). When I select the date, month and year, and click on set then the date shows in the UITextBox but days are not in correct format. When I set the date 02/16/1993(MM/DD/YYYY) then I got 02/47/1993 in UITextBox.Days are added (31 + 16 = 47), But i want to show 02/16/1993. My code is:

```
NSArray *allViews=[dateSheet subviews];
    for (UIView *subView in allViews)
    {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIDatePicker class]])
        {
            self.birthdate=[(UIDatePicker *)subView date];
        }
    }
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter= [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    [txtDOB setText:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.birthdate]];
```

What should I do to get correct format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    NSString *strDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
    txtDOB.text = strDate;
```

But I think there's something wrong in setting up your date picker. You should declare the date picker in your .h file.

Comment: I do that and I get the correct format but now i get this-> CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update........ What is this and how i remove this error which is in debug area

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the problem is with the day being displayed as 'day of the year' rather than 'day of the month'.
Which may likely be because of you using 'DD' instead of 'd' for calculating day..

See: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns

You can fix that in 'setDateFormat' string.
Otherwise I will suggest you to use NSDateComponents, that will not only give accurate results but also a low margin of error...